# Why Pytest Xdist Plugin Error isn`t working?

Tags: plugins, pycharm, pytest, xdist

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8vH8.png)PS C:\Users\мвидео\PycharmProjects\UDEMY-PythonTestAutomationWithPytest> pytest -n auto
================================================================================= test session starts =================================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.10.5, pytest-7.3.2, pluggy-1.2.0
django: settings: api.coronavstech.coronavstech.settings (from env)
rootdir: C:\Users\мвидео\PycharmProjects\UDEMY-PythonTestAutomationWithPytest
configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: django-4.5.2, xdist-3.3.1
created: 12/12 workersINTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\мвидео.virtualenvs\UDEMY-PythonTestAutomationWithPytest-H9kBCCAE\lib\site-packages_pytest\main.py", line 267, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     config.hook.pytest_sessionstart(session=session)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\мвидео.virtualenvs\UDEMY-PythonTestAutomationWithPytest-H9kBCCAE\lib\site-packages\pluggy_hooks.py", line 433, in **call**
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self.name, self._hookimpls, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\мвидео.virtualenvs\UDEMY-PythonTestAutomationWithPytest-H9kBCCAE\lib\site-packages\pluggy_manager.py", line 112, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\мвидео.virtualenvs\UDEMY-PythonTestAutomationWithPytest-H9kBCCAE\lib\site-packages\pluggy_callers.py", line 155, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>     sendexec(
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\мвидео.virtualenvs\UDEMY-PythonTestAutomationWithPytest-H9kBCCAE\lib\site-packages\execnet\gateway_bootstrap.py", line 79, in sendexec
INTERNALERROR>     io.write((repr(source) + "\n").encode("ascii"))
INTERNALERROR> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 32-37: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "", line 0

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Hello! Please tell me, I understand that the problem is most likely in Cyrillic. What are the options?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.